# How to find the width and breadth of a sparse array in Excel (and Google Sheets)?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Suppose you have a grid of cells in Excel (an up to date version, such as is in Office 365). Without using VB, but definitely *with* standard functions (i.e. programmatically, not "manually") how would you find the *BREADTH* and *DEPTH* of the grid, (or the name of, or ref to, the grid's Bottom Right Cell would do) given that:

- You are provided with the name of the Top Left Cell (TLC)
- *BREADTH* = the number of columns between the TLC and rightmost non-null cell in the widest row
- *DEPTH* = the number of rows from the TLC to the lowest (i.e. highest row numbered) non-null cell in the deepest column
- You may *not* assume the position of either the widest row or the deepest column. i.e. The widest row need not be at the top or bottom of the array, and the deepest column need not be at the extreme left or right.
- The array may be sparse; i.e. there may be blanks above and to the left of cells with values

Again: no VB; but no clicky-draggy-keyboardy manual stuff either. However, array formulae are fine, and while non-volatiles are much preferred, volatiles are tolerable.

If anyone knows the answer for Google Sheets, and it is very different from that for Excel, that would be appreciated too.
thanks!

By way of example, given the grid shown below, and a value of "B4" for the TLC, I'd want to have returned either a BREADTH of 7 and DEPTH of 8, or a BRC of "H11".

[image: Excel Grid Example]

Answer (score 1):

OK well here is a fairly brute force approach for Excel only to find the last row - use Offset to get each row from B4 onwards in the whole sheet, then subtotal to see it contains any non-blank cells, then multiply by the row number and use max to find the largest row number with some content:

```
=MAX((SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(B4,ROW(B4:B1048576)-ROW(B4),0,1,16384-COLUMN(B4)))>0)*ROW(B4:B1048576))

=MAX((SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(B4,0,COLUMN(B4:XFD4)-COLUMN(B4),1048576-ROW(B4),1))>0)*COLUMN(B4:XFD4))
```

Must be entered as array formulas using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>
<kbd>Enter</kbd>

You can get the breadth and depth trivially by subtracting the row or column of B4.

[image]

The response is a little sluggish as may be expected but tolerable.

You can also use Countif:

```
=MAX((COUNTIF(OFFSET(B4,ROW(B4:B1048576)-ROW(B4),0,1,16384-COLUMN(B4)),"<>")>0)*ROW(B4:B1048576))

=MAX((COUNTIF(OFFSET(B4,0,COLUMN(B4:XFD4)-COLUMN(B4),1048576-ROW(B4),1),"<>")>0)*COLUMN(B4:XFD4))
```

but it doesn't get round the issue of Offset being a volatile function so any change to the spreadsheet forces re-calculation.

Speed can be greatly increased if you can restrict the range. Also the Google Sheets approach mentioned in other answers can be used, e.g.

```
=MAX(IF(B4:L20<>"",ROW(B4:L20)))
```

However this appears to run out of resources if applied to a whole Excel sheet.

Answer (score 1):

This answer will work for **depth** in Google Sheets

```
=max(arrayformula(if(<range> <> "", row(<range>)))) - (row(<range>)-1)
```

where you substitute your sparse array coordinates for a maximum possible `<range>` starting in your Top Left Cell, e.g. A1:D20 or whatever if your TLC is A1. Note that if your array does not start in row 1, we just substract the starting row.

*This assumes that you can declare the "maximum possible range". But this seems a safe assumption: Either you have data spanning downwards for an indefinite number of rows and nothing specific below, when you just put a Very Large Number, or you do have something specific below, in which case you limit your range to the rows above it.*

Here is an example for TLC=J2

[image]

Finding the equivalent formula for **breadth** is left as a (not very demanding) exercise for the reader :-)

Answer (score 1):

this formula will show you the "BRC":

```
=ADDRESS(
 MAX(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A:Z<>"", ROW(A:Z))))-(ROW(A:Z)-1), 
 MAX(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A:Z<>"", COLUMN(A:Z))))-(COLUMN(A:Z)-1), 4)
```

[image: 0]